# Failed Audit when the post looked good to me

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits

I started reviewing a couple of **Low quality post** and suddenly I failed an audit, when I thought the posted content looked good. I read the post carefully but I am still not able to understand why it's a bad post and an audit failure.

Can anyone guide me so I can keep it in mind when reviewing in the future.

I would welcome any suggestion in this.

Here is snap shot:

> [image]

Comment: Without comments down-vote doesn't help me at all, please leave the reason as well.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. You clicked "Looks Good" on that post, and it told you that you failed the audit? You didn't do *anything else*? [The question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22495202/upgrade-entity-framework-to-6-1-index-already-exists-errors) has received no downvotes and has never been closed.

Comment: @CodyGray same is my question, that when I read this post it looks fine to me hence, when I got it in low quality row I clicked as Looks Good but result say I was wrong and the review was failed.

Comment: I don't see that [in your review history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1371853/rdc?tab=activity&sort=reviews&page=1). Is this something only moderators can see?

Comment: @CodyGray: the user has scrolled down to the qusetion, the *answer* (which has most likely been deleted) is what's being audited here. As you can see, the question is greyed out.

Comment: @MartinSmith: posts that have been deleted or where the action taken is "Recommend Deletion" will not show up normally in a user's public review history. Only moderators and the reviewer can see these reviews.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy There is a deleted answer on that question that was marked as spam. Quite subtle spam though and  does contain code and look as though it might be helpful.

Comment: That's possible, @Qantas. But doesn't the content also gray out after you fail an audit?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4940062 <- the audit. Mod-deleted answer that had spam or offensive flags.

Comment: Answer looks reasonable enough for LQ review, though. Not the greatest, and probably needed editing for the commercial, but it had a code snippet that could very well have been correct as far as this Java guy knows.

Comment: @RDC: I am not a downvoter (in fact, an upvoter actually), but I think some people consider your question weird based on the attached screenshot as Cody was also surprised. That may be at least one reason for the downvotes. I agree that it is uncool to get unexplained downvotes overall, so I am just speculating here what they may have thought...

Comment: If people have to try to figure out what you're actually asking, before even beginning to try to answer the question, it's a bad question. Downvoted.

Comment: Is this screenshot an artefact of the OP being on less than 10k and unable to see deleted posts? Scrolling down on @Mat's link doesn't just show the question and audit result for me.

Comment: @MartinSmith, I don't think so.  The OP had to see a version of the deleted answer to review it.  (Unless there's a very cruel bug in the review system!)

Comment: -1 because though you may have been unable to take a screenshot before the answer disappeared - if you were paying any attention what so ever you must know that the question you display here was not the post you were reviewing.........

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Answer as sussed out by *Qantas 94 Heavy*, *Martin Smith* and *Mat* in the comments:

[Your failed audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4940062) (10K link) was on an *answer* to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22495202/331508), not what you show in the screengrab in your question.
The answer was subtle spam and thus deleted.

You probably saw this:

> [image: Bad, bad post]

So it might not be obvious at a casual glance that this was spam.

Comment: Whow. That definitely is the best hidden Spam I have ever seen. Normally spammers are bot-ddriven but this definitely was a human - that knew some programming - that put together this post.

Comment: @TomTom, It was probably human but he stole the code snippit from another answer. No programming knowledge required.

Comment: Still - a ton more effort than a bot.

Comment: +1 but wow, so now I know, when reviewing, hover the mouse over the links *just in case*!

Comment: @TomTom [not the first time they have done it](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7218/169736)